# How to solve import error for created component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a Html template at my Sharetribe Flex website which is build in ReactJS. I have added HomePage container, but it following error :

./src/routeConfiguration.js
Attempted import error: 'HomePage' is not exported from './containers'.

What I have tried:

I had added following code in routeConfiguration.js

---

```
const routeConfiguration = () => {   return [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HomePage',
      component: props => <HomePage {...props} />,
    },
```

---

Pl. help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The error suggests the issue is with the `containers` file. Either you're importing from the wrong file, or the file isn't exporting the component. If you show the source in the `containers` file we can better help you.

Comment: @Hussein Duvigneau I have given source in the containers below :

Answer (score 0):

As you're exporting HomePage as default, the import in `routeConfiguration.js` should be `import HomePage from 'containers';` - it's a common typo to put `{}` around the imported component and I'm guessing you may have done the same.

If not, then you need to check your env config files (babel, typescript, etc).

Comment: It means that I have to do changes in babe, typescripts and then the HomePage will be imported?

Comment: Does `routeConfiguration` have `import HomePage from 'containers';`? (without `{}`)

Answer (score 0):

There are pages exported from src/containers/index.js file.

When JavaScript module bundler sees a module import with syntax like:

```
import { ComponentA, ComponentB } from '../containers'
```

it will assume that there is a file "../containers.js" or alternatively "../containers/index.js". In this case, the latter is true.

You should check Flex tutorials:
https://www.sharetribe.com/docs/tutorial-branding/add-faq-page/